# Removing master suffix from github zip file

Tags: git, github

Maybe there is a simple answer of this yet I wasn't able to find.

For example, I have a project on Github called "my-project". When I download it as a zip file, it becomes my-project-master.zip and unzipped folder name is my-project-master.

Is it possible to get rid of "master" suffix and simply download my project as my-project.zip and accordingly get my-project as folder name?

I've already tried creating a Release and it adds version suffix, pretty much same result.